# Align content with respect to headings

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code, I want all of my `<h5>` to be aligned.
I added `align-items-center` to my `row` div and it was working before I added the list.

Edit: I already have `padding: 0; margin: 0;` to my ul.

```css
.banner-section {
    padding: 80px 50px;
}
.spad {
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}
.section-title {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
.section-title h5 {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 38px;
    position: relative;
}
.section-title h5:before {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: -14px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 3px;
    background: #e7ab3c;
    content: "";
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.section-title h5 a {
    color: #252525;
}
.filter-subcategories {
    margin-left: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.filter-subcategories li, .filter-subcategories li a {
    color: #b2b2b2 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="banner-section spad">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 mb-3">
        <div class="section-title">
          <h5><a href="#">Men's Clothing</a> </h5>
        </div>

        <div class="section-details d-flex justify-content-center">
          <ul class="filter-subcategories">
            <li class="filter-subcategorys">
              <a href="#">Bags</a>
            </li>
            <li class="filter-subcategorys">
              <a href="#">Jackets</a>
            </li>
            <li class="filter-subcategorys">
              <a href="#">Shoes</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 mb-3">
        <div class="section-title">
          <h5><a href="#">Women's Clothing</a> </h5>
        </div>

        <div class="section-details d-flex justify-content-center">
          <ul class="filter-subcategories">
            <li class="filter-subcategorys">
              <a href="#">Misc</a>
            </li>
            <li class="filter-subcategorys">
              <a href="#">Tops</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 mb-3">
        <div class="section-title">
          <h5><a href="#">Kid's Clothing</a> </h5>
        </div>

        <div class="section-details d-flex justify-content-center">
          <ul class="filter-subcategories">
            <li class="filter-subcategorys">
              <a href="#">Jackets</a>
            </li>
            <li class="filter-subcategorys">
              <a href="#">Misc</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 mb-3">
        <div class="section-title">
          <h5><a href="#">Accessories &amp; Equipment</a> </h5>
        </div>

        <div class="section-details d-flex justify-content-center">
          <ul class="filter-subcategories">
            <li class="filter-subcategory">
              -
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 mb-3">
        <div class="section-title">
          <h5><a href="#">Sports Goods</a> </h5>
        </div>

        <div class="section-details d-flex justify-content-center">
          <ul class="filter-subcategories">
            <li class="filter-subcategory">
              -
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.filter-subcategories` remove `margin-left` and add `margin:0` and `padding: 0` to that class.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is of `ul` tag having default `padding` value. It'd be better if you include `css-normalizer` for your project or `set padding: 0` for `ul`

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the `filter-subcategories` class and use these rules:

```
.filter-subcategories {
    margin-left: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}
```